# Header isn't going straight across?

Tags: css

Can someone please tell me why this header wont go straight across? My goal is to have One call gets it all on the right side and the 800 phone number on the right. I placed them in there own div but the 800# is wrapping.

I've tried float, text-align and even span instead of div.

You can find the site here: http://jsfiddle.net/G78sd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two [block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes), which is why they're "wrapping". So one way to fix it would be to give each element a width and then float them.

```
.CompanyName {
    color: #330000;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    /* text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); */
    font-variant:small-caps;
    margin-top: 22px;
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
}

.HeaderPhoneNumber {
    color: #330000;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    /* text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); */
    font-variant:small-caps;
    width: 450px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quiet reply. I tried what you suggestions but still not working. It moves the number over a little but. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/G78sd/4/ any other suggestions?

Comment: See edited answer. You probably also want to fix the margin-top on the first element (or even them up), but I left that to you.

Comment: Yes I do i'm sure that's going to be another headache!! But this is a step in the right direction! Thank yoU!!!!